# How to stop Gmail moving emails to spam folder?

Tags: spam, gmail

Is there any way I could stop Gmail moving mails sent from my mail server to spam folder? We send users email confirmation links, but they are moved right to spam folder. So users who are less smarter or just miss the spam folder are not getting the confirmation email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting up SPF, DKIM and reverse DNS which may help out. Also, make sure your e-mails contain unsubscribe links.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. Could you say what does SPF and DKIM stand for?

Comment: SPF = Sender Policy Framework.  You can read more about SPF at the following URL:  [link](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction)

Here's a handy wizard for generating SPF records:

http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html


DKIM stands for DomainKeys Identified Mail and is a bit trickier, as it requires server side support. [link](http://www.dkim.org/)